# Restoring brick on new server failes -

Tags: filesystems, glusterfs

I am triying to attach a brick from another server to a local gluster development server. Therfore I have done a dd from a snapshot on production and a dd on the lvm volume on development. Then I deleted the .glusterfs folder on root.

Unfortunatelly forming a new brick failed nevertheless with the info that this brick is already part of a volume. (how does gluster know that?!)

I then issued the following:

```
sudo setfattr -x trusted.gfid /bricks/staging/brick1/
sudo setfattr -x trusted.glusterfs.volume-id /bricks/staging/brick1/
sudo /etc/init.d/glusterfs-server restart
```

**Magically gluster still seems to know that this brick is from another server** as it knows the peered gluster nodes which are aparently different on the dev server:

```
sudo gluster volume create staging node1:/bricks/staging/brick1
```

Error msg:

```
volume create: staging: failed: Staging failed on gs3. Error: Host node1 is not in 'Peer in Cluster' state

Staging failed on gs2. Error: Host node1 is not in 'Peer in Cluster' state
```

Is there a way to achive a restorage of that brick on a new server? Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `trusted.glusterfs.volume-id` extended atribute is set to any of the directories in `/bricks/staging/brick1/`. This is whan Gluster uses to see if the brick is not part of an other volume (or placed inside an other brick).

```
$ sudo getfattr -e hex -n rusted.glusterfs.volume-id /bricks/staging/brick1
$ sudo getfattr -e hex -n rusted.glusterfs.volume-id /bricks/staging
$ sudo getfattr -e hex -n rusted.glusterfs.volume-id /bricks
```

If any of these show a volume-id, you can remove it with the `setfattr` command you used earlier.